# Duplicate Variable

Tags: apex

I am pretty new to Apex, and I am coming from a c# background. I am having a duplicate variable error with this code, and I can't figure out why.  The error message is :

> Description   Save error: Duplicate variable: results (attempt to
>   re-create the variable with type: S)

```
public static List<Opportunity>  getUpcomingOpportunities(ID opportunityID) {


    List<Opportunity> results = new List<Opportunity>();


           if (exhibitID == null){
             system.debug('Exhibit ID is null');

             results = [SELECT Id, End_Date__c,StageName,Start_Date__c,Account.Name,  Account.BillingCity, Account.BillingState, Booking__r.Name , (SELECT 
                              PricebookEntry.product2.Family,PricebookEntry.product2.Id, PricebookEntry.product2.Public_Exhibit_Name__c   FROM OpportunityLineItems  )
                          FROM Opportunity
                          where 
                          Id in (SELECT OpportunityId  FROM OpportunityLineItem ) 
                          and   StageName = 'Booked'  and Booking__r.Name not in ( 'Master', 'Sponsor') 
                          and  End_Date__c >= :Date.today() order by Start_Date__c];



           }
           else{
             system.debug('Exhibit ID is ' + exhibitID);S
             results = [SELECT Id, End_Date__c,StageName,Start_Date__c,Account.Name,  Account.BillingCity, Account.BillingState, Booking__r.Name , (SELECT 
                              PricebookEntry.product2.Family,PricebookEntry.product2.Id, PricebookEntry.product2.Public_Exhibit_Name__c   FROM OpportunityLineItems  )
                          FROM Opportunity
                          where 
                          Id in (SELECT OpportunityId  FROM OpportunityLineItem where PricebookEntry.product2.Id = :opportunityID) 
                          and   StageName = 'Booked'  and Booking__r.Name not in ( 'Master', 'Sponsor') 
                          and  End_Date__c >= :Date.today() order by Start_Date__c];

           }
           return results;

        }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spurious `S` at the end of this line:

```
system.debug('Exhibit ID is ' + exhibitID);S
```

is being interpreted as the data type of the `results` variable on the next line and so generating the error.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I thought it had something to do with the list declaration.  You are awesome.

Comment: @ChrisMullins No problem. I've had plenty of obscure compilation errors to look at in Apex; the compiler's error reporting isn't as helpful as compilers for some other languages.